# Trained GradientBoostedClassifier assigns zero importance to any feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, ensemble-learning

First some facts regarding the scenario:
i try to predict some classes using 28 features (feature engineering completed) in scikit-learn. I had a huge dataset which i had to to split into 7 datasets depending on one specific feature that massively influenced the decision making process of models.

Finally, i had X datasets and used GridSearch for each of those to find the best/good set of hyperparameters. For this, i used 4 models ( Decision Stump as Baseline, DecisionTree, RandomForest, GradientBoostedTrees). Afterwards, i wanted to analyze the best estimators to extract feature importances and make further specific feature engineering for each dataset independently.

The first 4 dataset feature importances seemed quite fine to me. However, starting from the 5th dataset, trained GBDT assigns zero feature importance to all features. The other classifiers behave as expected.

For some context, here is a concrete example:

Feature importance of one dataset:

[image: feature importance of one dataset]

Model accuracy:

[image: Model accuracy]

I searched on the internet for this and found only one relevant thread were the answers were, besides "give more context please" and "maybe some errors?", the fact that the trained classifier could have learned something trivial. However, i analyzed all trees of the GBDT and indeed, it seems no feature is used, every tree has one layer and looks like this

```
digraph Tree {
node [shape=box];
0 [label = friedman_mse = 0.135
   samples = 106
   values = 0.054
];
}
```

Has someone an explanation for this? many many thanks :)

Comment: Can you add more context here :p? The title says about `GradientBoostingClassifier` from scikit, but in the question you wrote `GradientBoostedTrees` (which is from Spark). Also showing how you initialised the models would help.

Comment: Yes sure :)
I am using scikit-learn.
The models were learned by providing sets of hyperparameters for GridSearch. Finally, the best-performing models were chosen.

Comment: To be more concrete, one model looks like this:
GradientBoostingClassifier(criterion='friedman_mse', init=None,
              learning_rate=0.16, loss='deviance', max_depth=2,
              max_features='log2', max_leaf_nodes=None,
              min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
              min_samples_leaf=65, min_samples_split=60,
              min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=35,
              presort='auto', random_state=None, subsample=0.82, verbose=0,
              warm_start=False)